# How to I get the app's favicon to display on a ttkBootrap Dialog messagebox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started using ttkBootstrap to style my Tkinter application. I'm able to display the ttkBootstrap yesno() messagebox when the escape key is pressed. The app's 'darkly' theme is applied to the messagebox. However, unlike the Tkinter messagebox, the app's favicon is not pass through to the popup. The dialog window shows the ttkBootatrap favicon. Is there an option that would allow me to use the app's favicon?
The ttkbootstrap version is 1.10

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttkbs
from ttkbootstrap import dialogs

root = ttkbs.Window()

root.iconbitmap('./wolftrack.ico')

style = ttkbs.Style(theme='darkly')

root.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: confirm_quit())

def confirm_quit() -> None:
    reply = dialogs.Messagebox.yesno(
        title='Exit Application',
        message='Do you want to quit the application?',
        alert=True
    )

    if reply:
        root.quit()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried adding the attributes parent to the yesno() method.

`parent=root`

This still displayed the ttkBootrap favicon.

Next, I try iconbitmap. While this was not an attribute listed in the docs, it don't produce an error. However, it also did not change the favicon.

Comment: Do like ```root = ttkbs.Window(iconphoto=None)```.